# CAPE inflation adjustment

Tags: stock-analysis, stock-valuation

How does the CAPE calculation take into account inflation?

I thought that previous years earnings were discounted by prior year's inflation into today's money and then averaged. If that were the case I would expect 1/CAPE to be the notional yield for the next year BEFORE inflation.

For example if earnings exactly kept pace with inflation over the last 10 years and in the last year were $100 then the inflation-adjusted average of the last 10 years earnings would also be $100. If the current price was $2000 I would expect the CAPE to be 20 and the yield = (1/CAPE) = 5%

So if I'm using CAPE to notionally predict next year's earnings, and inflation were 2%, I would do:
$2000 * 5% * (1 + 2%) = $102 and this would be in line with the previous years.
The value to me as an investor would be less because the $2000 capital would be worth 2% less after a year. So the real return AFTER inflation a year from now is close to 3%.

This seems to be the same as the calculation explained here under "How to Calculate the P/E 10 Ratio" which they say is the same as CAPE.
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pe10ratio.asp

Then I read the following article by Shiller which explains Excess CAPE Yield (ECY).

https://www.project-syndicate.org/commentary/making-sense-of-soaring-stock-prices-by-robert-j-shiller-et-al-2020-11

Key sentence: "To calculate the ECY, we simply invert the CAPE ratio to get a yield and then subtract the ten-year real interest rate". Which I've seen interpreted as:

Excess CAPE Yield = (1/CAPE) - (Treasury10YearYield - Inflation)

Which seems to be a measure of the risk-premium you are being offered for holding shares over a risk-free investment. But my confusion is that the term on the left is BEFORE inflation (I think) and the term on the right is definitely AFTER inflation. If true Excess CAPE Yield would be comparing apples with pears. So then I thought I must have misunderstood CAPE and 1/CAPE must also somehow be AFTER inflation.

e.g. if Treasury10YearYield = 5% also then Excess CAPE Yield = 5% - (5% - 2%) = 2%
but earnings from treasuries also $100, so no better than the original investment.

Which part of my interpretation or calculation is wrong please?

Comment: "if I'm using CAPE to notionally predict next year's earnings" - nothing in CAPE predicts the future, does it? It simply says how expensive the current price is, compared with an extended period of earnings.

Comment: Yes indeed. So sloppy wording perhaps. I'm just trying to give the analogy to what a treasury bond would give. What Shiller calls the Yield = (1/CAPE). It's not really a yield of course as nothing is yielded but it's just for comparison purposes to ensure all parts are before or after inflation. Make sense?

Comment: Sure, earnings yields can be compared to bond yields. Maybe, edit your question to focus on ECY.

Comment: Well ECY is a clear calculation (from the article) once you have CAPE. It just doesn't make any sense to me which makes me think my understanding of CAPE must be wrong. What do you think?

Comment: S&P 500 CAPE is ~38.62 so notional yield is ~2.59%. 10y Treasury is 1.30%. US CPI is predicted to be about 4% over the next 12 months. What do you think the risk-premium of shares is? I would have previously said 1.29%, which is not much. But Shiller seems to be saying 5.29% which is a lot more (or 4% when the article was written)